# How to make the text in the table left-aligned, centered, and beautifully wrapped?

Tags: tables, tabularx

Dear experienced friends, I am trying to insert a long paragraph into my table. However, I found that no matter I used the `p` as paragraph or used `c`, the text cannot be wrapped beautifully. I hope the context can:

- The words are left aligned.
- The whole paragraph is in the center&left of the cell.
- The length of the cell is fixed. (I used `w{c}{30mm}` but it doesn't work.)

Could you mind giving me some hints? Thank you so much!

---

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\caption{Set the content in the middle center of the table}
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.1}

\begin{tabular}{*{1}{p{30mm}}*{5}{w{c}{10mm}}}

\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Content} & A & B & C & D \\ [1ex]
 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{The content} & & & & \\ [0.5ex]

\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\multirow{9}{2em}{Here is the text contect that I want to beautifully aligned in the middle center} & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ [0.5ex]

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\label{table_main}
\end{table}
```

Here is what I try to achieve:

[image]

And sadly here is what my code can achieve:

[image]

Comment: Replace `\multirow{9}{2em}`  with  `\multirow{9}{=}`   since the first column is 30 mm wide

Comment: @Bernard You are my hero man! Can't believe I ignore this. And the problem is already solved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Comment: You just need to increase a length specified as the second argument of `\multirow`. `2em` is I think an equivalent of two letters `m`; I guess it's about `1cm`. By default, the second argument is usually given as `*` or `=` (see [documentation](https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf))

Comment: Thank you for the ref @Celdor. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask to use a textwidth of 2em, TeX will do it. When the `\multirow` material is in a “fixed width“ column, use `=` instead.

Don't pollute your table with `\\[0.5ex]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\caption{Set the content in the middle center of the table}
\label{table_main}

\medskip % or set the caption below, or load caption

\begin{tabular}{*{1}{p{30mm}}*{5}{w{c}{10mm}}}

\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Content} & A & B & C & D \\
 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{The content} & & & & \\ 

\cmidrule(r){1-2}
\multirow{9}{=}{Here is the text contect that I want to beautifully aligned in the middle center} & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some points to note.

1. The standard classes are set up for captions below tables. So either add some vertical space or load `caption` that changes the parameters for captions above tables.
2. The label should go after (or inside) the `\caption`. Placing it after the `tabular` will make document maintenance more difficult.
3. Polluting the `tabular` with `\\[0.5ex]` makes it impossible for `\multirow` to guess the right placement; use `\arraystretch` and ***never*** do `\def`.
4. (Most important.) I'm not a fan of `\multirow` and I always look for ways to do without it. In this particular case, it seems that the text is some explanation common for all the rows. As such it should go *outside* the table. For instance below it, so the text width can be more generous and readers will have less hard time in parsing it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\caption{Set the content in the middle center of the table}
\label{table_main}

\medskip % or set the caption below, or load caption

\begin{tabular}{*{5}{w{c}{10mm}}}

\toprule
Content & A & B & C & D \\
 
\midrule
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]

\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\dimexpr50mm+10\tabcolsep}@{}}{
  Here is the text contect that I want to beautifully aligned in the middle center}

\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So excellent and comprehensive answer. I really appreciate your solution as well as your suggestions for a beautiful table! Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it is not entirely clear how should your table looks . I guess that it may be something like this:

[image]

In MWE, which produce above table I use `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\caption{Set the content in the middle center of the table}
\centering

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={Q[j, wd=33mm] *{5}{Q[c,m]}}}
%    \toprule
\SetCell[c=2]{c}{Content}   &   & A & B & C & D     \\ 
%    \midrule
\SetCell[r=9]{m}    Here is the text content that I want to beautifully aligned in the middle center
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                            & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
%    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\label{table_main}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**
or something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\caption{Set the content in the middle center of the table}
\centering

\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l, wd=32mm] *{5}{Q[c, wd=10mm]}}}
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=2]{c}{The Content}   &   & A & B & C & D \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-2}\cmidrule[l]{3-6}
\SetCell[r=9]{m}    Here is the text content that I want to beautifully aligned in the middle center
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                                & A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\label{table_main}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes I found that using `=` can perfectly solve all the problems. But your answer offers a brand new way to organize table. Really appreciate!